# Using RestTemplate in spring-boot returns with 404

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to send a body in a post request in a springboot application using rest template. Here is the controller:(I removed `@RequestBody` because I used `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header)

```
    @RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SentimentParserController {

    @Autowired
    private SentimentParserService sentimentParserService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public ResponseEntity<mcResponse>getTheSentiments(  mcSentimentRequestDTO sentimentRequestDTO){
        return  sentimentParserService.getSentimentsMc(sentimentRequestDTO);


    }
}
```

I want to send the `sentimentRequestDTO` object(lang, key, and text) as the body in a post request to get the mcResponse:

public mcResponse parseTheSentiments(String text, Languages lang, String key) throws Exception {

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String request = "http://localhost:8080";

mcSentimentRequestDTO mSentiments =new mcSentimentRequestDTO(key,"EN",text);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
map.add("key", key);
map.add("txt", text);
map.add("lang", Languages.ENGLISH.toString());
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request1 = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

mcResponse response = restTemplate.postForObject(request, request1 , mcResponse.class );

return response;
```

}

However, I am getting the following error: 404 null.

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance 
and here is the service class:

```
public ResponseEntity<mcResponse> getSentimentsMc(mcSentimentRequestDTO sentimentRequestDTO){
        ResponseEntity<mcResponse> dto = null;

                try {
                    dto = sentimentConverter.getTheSentiments(mcsParser.parseTheSentiments(sentimentRequestDTO.getText(),
                            Languages.ENGLISH, sentimentRequestDTO.getKey()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        return dto;
    }
```

Comment: Your mapping says `/something` but your request says `/`.

Comment: I changed the request to :http://localhost:8080/something,I now have the error 400 null

Comment: have you annotated class with `@RestController` ?

Comment: can you update your complete controller class? and also check spring boot application is running? how are you running these two programs ? @thecoder

Comment: i updated the controller and added the service class

Comment: url should be `String request = "http://localhost:8080/api/something";` @thecoder

Comment: still getting 400 null error

Comment: try this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574892/how-to-send-post-request-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-body

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574892/how-to-send-post-request-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-body

Answer (score 0):

Looks like variable request should be

```
String request = "http://localhost:8080/something";
```

Also if controller class has prefix, this prefix also should be in request.
I mean if your class looks like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myApi")
public class CertificateController {
....
@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<mcResponse>getTheSentiments(  mcSentimentRequestDTO sentimentRequestDTO){
        return  sentimentParserService.getSentimentsMc(sentimentRequestDTO);
}
```

Then request should be

```
String request = "http://localhost:8080/myApi/something";
```

Comment: @thecoder, if after that you have 400, I think you need add consumes parameter

`@RequestMapping(value = "/something", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`

Comment: The controller has no prefix

Comment: Try add parameter `consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` into RequestMapping annotation

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the controller isn't getting included in the spring context. If you just have an app annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, then make sure that your controller is in a package that is the same as or lower than your annotated application.

To check the controller is being picked up you can add the following logging options to your application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework.beans=debug
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping=trace
```

When your server starts up you should see something like the following in the log

`1.` To show the controller is in the spring-context

```
DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'sentimentParserController'
```

`2.` To show the mapping for the /api/something url

```
RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped 1 handler method(s) for class SentimentParserController: {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity SentimentParserController.getTheSentiments(mcSentimentRequestDTO)={[/api/something],methods=[POST]}}
```

If you see both of these, then what you say you're doing should work. Just make sure you are sending the request to `/api/something` and the server is running on port 8080.