# Calling REST Service from Servlet

Tags: rest, servlets, jax-rs

i am unable to call a REST Service from Servlet , the codes are as follows :-

**1) UserManagement.jsp :-**

```
<form action="./cs" method="post">  
        <p>ID : <input type="text" name="id" /></p>
        <p>Name : <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
        <p>Profession : <input type="text" name="profession" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="buttonselected" value="Add User" />
        <input type="submit" name="buttonselected" value="Show User" />
        <input type="submit" name="buttonselected" value="Update User" />
        <input type="submit" name="buttonselected" value="List Users" />
    </form>
```

**2) In ControllerServlet.java :-**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String str_buttonselected=request.getParameter("buttonselected");
           System.out.println("Button Selected = "+str_buttonselected);
           switch(str_buttonselected)
           {
           case "Add User":
               RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/UserService/add");
               rd.forward(request, response);   
               break;
               .......             
           }
    }
```

**3) UserService.java :-**

```
@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService 
{   
   UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
   private static final String SUCCESS_RESULT="<result>success</result>";
   private static final String FAILURE_RESULT="<result>failure</result>";

   @POST
   @Path("/add")
   @Produces("application/xml") 
   @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   public String createUser(@FormParam("id") int id, @FormParam("name") String name, @FormParam("profession") String profession) throws IOException
   {
      User user = new User(id, name, profession);
      int result = userDao.addUser(user);
      if(result == 1)
      {
         return SUCCESS_RESULT;
      }
      return FAILURE_RESULT;   
   }
}
```

Please suggest how to call the REST Service url from Servlet.

Thanks & Regards
Saswata Mandal.

Comment: I don't see in your code where you've tried anything.  What is your application server (i.e. Tomcat, Wildfly, etc.)?

Comment: tomcat :- tomee plus

Comment: Something like [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574892/how-to-send-post-request-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-body)