# How to add a body to POST call in HTTPURLConnection in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

How to add a body to POST call in HTTPURLConnection in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format (JAVA)

JDK version is 1.8

Code  tried:

```
               String  parameters = "key=value";
 OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(urlParameters);
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574892/how-to-send-post-request-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-body

Comment: @Mert The link was useful

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed Used:

```
               String  parameters = "key=value";
byte[] parameters = urlParameters.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
 OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(urlParameters);
```