# Receive Indeed API Access Token

Tags: python, curl, post, python-requests

I am trying to get the Indeed vacancies of my company via API with Python. I am following https://developer.indeed.com/docs/authorization/3-legged-oauth and https://mathiashaentjens.medium.com/how-do-you-extract-data-using-the-indeed-api-and-build-your-own-indeed-campaign-reporting-8127252ef073.

I create Indeed API keys and receive the Authorization Code, but I couldn't get Access Token. I send the same **POST** as documents via curl and Python requests but I got this error:

> {'error_description': 'Your request might include sensitive information passed in the URL query string. Parameters must be passed in the HTTP request body using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format (See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.3). For increased security, we recommend that you periodically rotate your application secret at [https://secure.indeed.com/account/apikeys.'](https://secure.indeed.com/account/apikeys.%27),
> 'error': 'invalid_request'}

My Python code is like:

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','accept':'application/json'}

payload = {'code':'XXXX', 'client_id':'XXXX', 'client_secret':'XXXX', 'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost', 'grant_type':'authorization_code'}

response = requests.post('https://apis.indeed.com/oauth/v2/tokens', params=urllib.parse.urlencode(payload), headers=headers)

response.json()
```

and via command line;

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Length: 0" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://apis.indeed.com/oauth/v2/tokens?code=XXXX&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code"`

Is there anyone familiar with this error?

Comment: Don't send the data as `params` send it as `data` or `json` if the API accepts that

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. now i got another error like `{'error_description': 'Invalid grant', 'error': 'invalid_grant'}`. I think i am right way. Thanks!

Comment: And now i can create the keys!!! thanks @KlausD.!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to transfer data as 'x-www-form-urlencoded' and not as JSON or in the query parameters, this can be checked using Postman.

[How to send post request with x-www-form-urlencoded body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574892/how-to-send-post-request-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-body)

Look at here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574892/how-to-send-post-request-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-body Look at here

Comment: It would be good to put the helpful link into the answer. Use the `Edit` button to edit the answer.

Comment: If this question can be resolved by merely dropping a link to another Stack Overflow page, then this page should be closed a duplicate of the nominated page.